# why can't i make "bill-photo" center?

Tags: html, css

am i messing up the positioning? trying to avoid using margins. sorry for a silly question - new to this!

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/minacosentino/pen/YxLLQw)

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.jumbotron::before {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.bill-photo {
  position: relative;
  width: 15rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding margins?

Comment: is there a way to do so without them? i'm trying to understand the best way to do it i suppose. would it be better to use a column to lock it in for responsive purposes? beginner here! :)

Comment: You have a good amount of options; it all depends on what you are trying to achieve. Is it just horizontal centering? Then add `margin: 0 auto;` to the `.bill-photo` rule. If you have more specific requirements, you should update your question with those details. There's also other styles affecting that photo that are in your codepen but not explained here; might want to include an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: yeah i tried that margin rule, but it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: It does if you reduce your screen size. Reread my (edited) comment above, you should attempt to reproduce this with the minimal amount of CSS to see why it's not working.

Comment: If you're goint to use `margin: 0 auto` you need to also set the image to `display: block`. https://codepen.io/justdan/pen/RZmZWw

Comment: thank you all for your help! new lesson that i'll definitely remember :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using text-align css property on your .container class.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
```

This should resolve your issue and give you the desired effect.

Hope it helps. Cheers!